# How to use ACRA to send custom reports?

Tags: java, android, acra

ACRA allows you to send reports when an application is destroyed. How to use it to send a report during the necessary moment? For example, in block:

```
    try {
        // some code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // send custom report with exception stack trace
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize ACRA:

```
ACRA.init(this);
ErrorReporter.getInstance().addReportSender(new CustomReportSender());
```

Try to use following:

```
    try {
        // some code
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It also works without `ErrorReporter.getInstance().addReportSender(new CustomReportSender());`